# SimpleXMLElement and encoding problems

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, simplexml

I load a RSS (XML) document into an SimpleXmlElement the following way:

```
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
```

I'we also tested with:

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($content);
```

When I print out the $content the encoding is correct but when I load it into an SimpleXmlElement and print it out, I get things like;  'vÃ¦re' instead of 'være'.

Any idea how to fix this?

Also, extra question, the SimpleXmlElement seems slow, any way to speed it up?

**[Edit]**

RSS source: http://www.vg.no/rss/nyfront.php?frontId=1

And it seems that it was something else that was my bottle neck (the foreach running trough all of my RSS news entries).

Comment: What encoding are you doing the output in? And re slowness, are you 100% sure that is SimpleXML, and not the outgoing request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Need to use utf8_decode().

Refrence: http://lists.motion-twin.com/pipermail/phptal/2005-March/000316.html